# Any external QR scanner device with cordova/ionic support?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am using using ionic framework to build a QR reading app. I would like to use an external QR code scanner that can connect to the app either through bluetooth or through usb(android) and be able to read the scanned QR on the app.

Are there any QR scanner device in support with cordova/ionic support?

I have tried searching in google, but didn't find anything regarding QR scanner external device

QR scanner plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner
but doesn't seem to have any support for external QR scanner device

```
import { QRScanner, QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr- 
scanner/ngx';


 constructor(private qrScanner: QRScanner) { }

 ...

// Optionally request the permission early
this.qrScanner.prepare()
.then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
 if (status.authorized) {
   // camera permission was granted


   // start scanning
   let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((text: string) => 
  {
     console.log('Scanned something', text);

     this.qrScanner.hide(); // hide camera preview
     scanSub.unsubscribe(); // stop scanning
   });

 } else if (status.denied) {
   // camera permission was permanently denied
   // you must use QRScanner.openSettings() method to guide the user to the settings page
   // then they can grant the permission from there
 } else {
   // permission was denied, but not permanently. You can ask for permission again at a later time.
 }
  }).catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
```

If someone could recommend any QR scanner device that supports the above process that would be great! thanks in advance!